# Can webapp2 get data from a non-form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

the self.request.get method can help to fetch value from a form.

But what if i need to get the value from a non-form object. For example

```
<ul name = "testing-ul">Testing list</ul>
```

How can i get the "Testing list" from using webapp2?

Comment: Either use the solution suggested below, or us javascript to submit the form payload and include the contents of the ul as well

Answer (score 2):

Does it that information have to be in a `<ul>`? Can you duplicate it in a hidden form element, thats how most people do this. Set up the field objects as if a user entered it and wrap it up in

```
<div style="display:none;"><!--your elements here--></div>
```